# STM32 Timer, variable frequency output

Tags: stm32, timer

### preface

in the AVRs, when I wanted to create a variable frequency waveform (50% duty cycle) within a limited range defined by timer frequency and its prescaler, I used CTC mode:

[image: CTC Mode, atmega8 datasheet]

the OCR registers work both as a TOP value for the timer (or Auto-reload value in ST's nomenclature) and as a compare match with their related IO control (e.g. toggle on match or force HI on match). so I could make a variable frequency with setting just one register (aside from the prescaler).

### The problem

the STM32 has 2 different registers for this purpose. while the AVRs had a single OCR register, the STM32 has the TOP value set by ARR (auto-reload register) and the output control with CCR (capture/compare register).

so when we want to variate the frequency, we have to set both registers; ARR for the frequency and the CCR for just keeping the duty cycle of the waveform at 50%. and it seems pretty much the same procedure for activating PWM, despite the different bit settings:

[image: Output compare modes, STM32F0 reference manual]

### The question

is there an easier way (single register setting) to get a variable frequency on a pin, with the timer in STM32?

[STM32F0 ref. manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/DM00031936-.pdf). the timers with similar numbering are similar on various models so the model number or family doesn't matter.

Comment: Use mode '011' to toggle the output. It'll then always produce a 50% duty cycle and the period will be double the value you load into the CCR.

Comment: @brhans I think you still need to modify `ARR`, because timer continues to count after a `CCR` match.

Comment: BTW, I wonder why OP wants single register access. Both `ARR` and `CCR` registers have *preload* functionality. Writing multiple registers is also possible using DMA in *burst mode*.

Comment: @Tagli I didn't know CCR have preload too. I thought I was doing it wrong

Comment: Of course you need to enable it using OCxPE bit in CCMRn.